# Ionic 2: two datetime fields returning same value

Tags: datetime, angular, typescript, ionic2

I am using ionic 2 and trying to allow a user to select a date and a time in two separate `ion-datetime` fields.

The HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="newEventForm">
  ...
    <ion-item>
        <ion-datetime formControlName="date" displayFormat="MMM DD, YYYY" [(ngModel)]="eventDate" min="2017-01-01" max="2020-10-31"></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-datetime formControlName="time" displayFormat="h:mm a" [(ngModel)]="eventTime"></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
        <button ion-button block default (click)="addEvent()">Add Event</button>
    </ion-item>
</form>
```

The Typescript:

```
export class NewEventPage {

    eventTime: String = new Date().toISOString();
    eventDate: String = new Date().toISOString();

    constructor(...) {
        ...
        this.newEventForm = formBuilder.group({
            ...,
            date: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
            time: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
        });
    }

    public addEvent() {
        if(!this.newEventForm.valid) {
            console.error("Validation problems");
        } else {
            console.log("Form is valid", this.newEventForm.value);
        }
    }
}
```

When I click the submit button, I get everything back, but I'm getting the same dateTime for both date and time, even though I'd like it to be different.  They both return whatever the `date` is and it seems the `time` does not change.

Any thoughts on why this could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try changing...

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-datetime formControlName="date" displayFormat="MMM DD, YYYY" [(ngModel)]="eventDate" min="2017-01-01" max="2020-10-31"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
  <ion-datetime formControlName="time" displayFormat="h:mm a" [(ngModel)]="eventTime"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

to

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-datetime formControlName="date" displayFormat="MMM DD, YYYY" [(ngModel)]="eventDate" (ngModelChange)="eventDate" min="2017-01-01" max="2020-10-31"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
  <ion-datetime formControlName="time" displayFormat="h:mm a" [(ngModel)]="eventTime" (ngModelChange)="eventTime"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

ngModelChange will update the variable everytime it is changed.  Probably simplest way to get it working.